# Python: system command

Tags: python, windows, command, system, os.system

I spend a few hours writing a little script.
Basically what it does is create a new text file and fills it up with whatever.
I zip the text file --using zipfile-- and here's where my problem lies.

I want to run the Windows system command:

`copy /b "imgFile.jpg" + "zipFile.zip" newImage.jpg`
To merge the image "imgFile.jpg" and the zip "zipFile.zip".

So:

`os.system("copy /b \"imgFile.jpg\" + \"zipFile.zip\" newImage.jpg")`

When I run my script, it all seems to go fine.
But when it's done and I try to extract the 'newImage.jpg' file, it gives me:

`The archive is either in unknown format or damaged`

This ONLY happens when I run the system command within the script.
It works fine when I use the shell. It even works if I use a separate script.

I've double checked my zip file. Everything is in good shape.
Is there something I'm doing wrong? Something I'm not seeing?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using shutil?

```
import shutil
shutil.copy(src, dst)
```

Answer (score 0):

There may be a problem with the way Python is passing the arguments to the shell command. Try using [subprocess.call](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#using-the-subprocess-module). This method takes arguments as an array and passes them that way to the command:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(["copy", "/b", '"imgFile.jpg" + "zipFile.zip"', "newImage.jpg"])
```